# File Recovery from thumb drive - Bad Superblock

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, mount, filesystem

So I have a 64GB SanDisk Cruzer Glide, and recently something happened to it. Whenever I would try to fsck it said the magic number for the superblock was corrupted, I didn't know what that meant, so I backed up everything with dd to a 1TB hard drive.

I formatted it as exFAT in macOS, and put it back into my Pi 400. I tried to mount the .img file to a directory I made so I can try to copy the files over to the thumb drive, so I can then copy them to my hard drive, but whenever I try to mount the .img file, I get this...

```
root@ubuntu:/home/wolfyn_claw# mkdir /mnt/glide2
root@ubuntu:/home/wolfyn_claw# mount -o loop '/media/wolfyn_claw/AC_STORAGE/glide2.img' /mnt/glide2
mount: /mnt/glide2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop17, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I'm attempting to write the .img file back to the thumb drive and see how that goes. I'm really hoping I can access the files on it, I can't afford to lose any of it.

[image: Unable to format on macOS]

I attempted to fsck the thumb drive, but whenever I do so it says the magic number in he superblock is invalid.

[image: Bad superblock]

Before I did this, I backed up the thumb drive `dev/sda1` to an .IMG file with dd. The file is ~63.5GB, and is stored on my hard drive.

Help is really appreciated, I really need to get these files back. Once it works again, I'll transfer everything to my 2TB SSD.

Comment: Please do not post text as images, but cut-and-paste the text.

Comment: This is one reason using `dd` to back up a data partition is an even worse idea than using it to back up a whole system. *Why??!??*  `cp -a` is your friend; then you are not dependent on any particular fs type.

Comment: Did you `dd` the whole thumb drive `/dev/sda` or only its partition `/dev/sda1`? What was exactly the command you used?

Comment: @goldilocks: In fact `dd` is the best command here. Of course *if the filesystem is accessible and not corrupt*, you can copy with `cp`. But if you need to do further forensics to get the files back, you should always work on a copy of the image, not on the image itself.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I guess I did misread the first paragraph -- if there is really nothing else you can do, fair enough. So all apologies (but I'll leave that comment in case anyone sees this and goes, "hey yeah I guess I could back up my data partition that way" >_<).  As Ingo implies, there is a bit of an issue here with the OP "paraphrasing" things that might as well be put literally: "I used `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=some.img bs=4M`" etc.

Comment: I backed up `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sda1`
@Ingo

Comment: Please execute `sudo parted sda.img print free` (not sda1.img) and add its output to your question. Please paste the text, don't use images!

Answer (score 3):

> so I backed up everything with dd to a 1TB hard drive.

That is the best action that you did. When you try anything, do it on a copy of this file, not on this file itself.

First make a copy of the image and work on that copy. If anything goes wrong, you will still have the original image.

The fact that you use `fsck` on the original image suggests that you have, at one point, formatted it as ext2/3/4. The original superblock is gone, but there may be valid backups. Use

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sda5 | grep -i superblock
```

to find them.

You will get lines that say

```
Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98537
```

So, try to mount it with:

```
mount -o sb=98304 -o loop '/media/wolfyn_claw/AC_STORAGE/glide2.img' /mnt/glide2
```

If that superblock does not work, try another one.

----- edit -----

You should have `dd`-ed the whole disk, probably with

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/some/image.img
```

In that case, you will need to mount the correct partition in the image.  You will need to mount it with an offset.

To determine the offset, do

```
fdisk -l imagefile
```

Calculate the `offset = start sector * size of a sector in bytes` and mount with

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=<offset you calculated> -t auto imagefile /mnt/mountpoint
```

Comment: Good advise but it doesn't help if he doesn't use the correct start sector of the partition. With wrong start sector he will also get the same error message and will not find other superblocks.

Comment: *"You should have dd-ed the whole disk"* -> How would this help?  It only complicates. BTW, if the OP is unsure it is simple to check with `fdisk -l image.img`; if it's the whole device you should get a sane partition table.

Comment: I'm using fsck because I thought that was the correct command to fix exFAT filesystems... Guess not.

Comment: I tried to find the offset, but I can't get a good enough result. 
`root@wC-ubmPi400:/media/wolfyn_claw/AC_STORAGE# dumpe2fs /dev/sdc1 | grep -i superblock`
`dumpe2fs 1.45.7 (28-Jan-2021)`
`dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1`
`Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`
`

Comment: I did the same thing for `dev/sdc`, and I got: `Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdc`

Comment: @goldilocks: the recovery of data from a broken device is something different than making a backup.